# Find the most powerful test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics

> On a particular day let $X_1, X_2$ & $X_3$ be the number of boys born before the first girl is born in hospital 1, 2, 3 respectively. If the observations are 0 ,3 & 2 respectively, find the most powerful test to test the null hypothesis that a girl and a boy are equally likely to be born against the alternative that a girl is less likely to be born than a boy.

I feel like I should use non parametric tests but I'm not sure as I'm not that familiar with this. I know all of them follow geometric. And I know sum of geometric is negative binomial but that doesn't help me.

Comment: My initial approach was to find mean of Xi-s, which is 1. Then the total number of boys born before girl should be near 3. I thought summing them would lead to negative binomial test, but the thing is negative binomial assures no of success, but we have no assurance of them occurring in different hospitals.

Comment: Indeed they follow geometric distributions. It is reasonable to assume that X1, X2, X3 are independent. So one wants to test p=1/2 vs p<1/2 based on a random sample of size 3 of a geometric distribution. Without further calculations it is unclear whether a UMP test exists, but you could probably start by considering likelihood ratio tests and hope that the test statistic does not depend on the specific alternative chosen.

Comment: So should I just test for geometric distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Before testing any statistical hypotheses, we need to specify a probabilistic model for data first.  In this problem, it is reasonable to assume $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is a random sample from the distribution (i.e., [the geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)):
\begin{align}
f_\theta(x) = P_\theta(X = x) = (1 - \theta)^x\theta, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ is the probability of having a girl.  Having set the stage as $(1)$, the hypotheses testing problem can be formulated as:
\begin{align}
H: \theta = \frac{1}{2} \text{ v.s. } K: \theta < \frac{1}{2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Since we have three independent observations (as opposed to a single observation), we need to consider the joint density of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$, which is given by
\begin{align}
p_\theta(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (1 - \theta)^{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}\theta^3, \quad x_i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}, i = 1, 2, 3.
\end{align}
By rewriting $p_\theta(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ as (where $T(\mathbf{x}) = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$)
\begin{align}
p_\theta(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \exp(\log(\theta^3(1 - \theta)^{x_1 + x_2 + x_3})) = \theta^3\exp(T(\mathbf{x})\log(1 - \theta)),
\end{align} it is clear that $p_\theta$ belongs to the *one-parameter exponential family*, whence by Corollary $3.4.1$ in *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* by Lehmann and Romano the UMP test (of size $\alpha$) $\phi$ for testing $(2)$ exists, which is
\begin{align}
\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
1 & T(\mathbf{x}) > C, \\
\gamma & T(\mathbf{x}) = C, \\
0 & T(\mathbf{x}) < C, \tag{3}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ and $C$ are determined by $E_{1/2}(\phi(T(\mathbf{X})) = \alpha$. [Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Distribution_of_a_sum_of_geometrically_distributed_random_variables) the sum of $r$ i.i.d. geometric $G(p)$ random variables has negative binomial distribution $NB(r, p)$, under $H$, it follows that $T(\mathbf{X}) \sim NB(3, 1/2)$, whence $E_{1/2}(\phi(T(\mathbf{X})) = \alpha$ becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{k > C} \binom{k + 2}{k}(0.5)^{k + 3} + \gamma\binom{C + 2}{C}(0.5)^{C + 3} = \alpha. \tag{4}
\end{align}

For $\alpha = 0.05$, as `pnbinom(8, 3, 0.5) = 0.9672852` and `pnbinom(7, 3, 0.5) = 0.9453125`, a good choice of $C$ to solve $(4)$ is $C = 8$, for which
$\gamma = \frac{0.05 - (1 - 0.9672852)}{0.02197266} = 0.7866667$ (in fact, this $(C, \gamma)$ is the unique solution to $(4)$ because $C$ must be a positive integer and $\gamma$ must be in $(0, 1)$). Hence $(3)$ can be written explicitly as
\begin{align}
\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
1 & T(\mathbf{x}) > 8, \\
0.7866667 & T(\mathbf{x}) = 8, \\
0 & T(\mathbf{x}) < 8.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

For the observed data $\mathbf{x} = (0, 3, 2)$, $T(\mathbf{x}) = 0 + 3 + 2 = 5 < 8$. Hence the null hypothesis $H$ is not rejected at $\alpha = 0.05$.